# Implementation of factory method in related class hierarchies

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism

Please see the code:

```
class X
{
  public string x;
}

class Y : X
{
  public string y;
}

class A
{
  string a;
  public virtual X createX<T>()
    where T : X, new()
  {
    return new T() { x = a };
  }
}

class B : A
{
  string b;
  public override X createX<T>()
  {
    var x = base.createX<T>();
    if (x is Y)
      ((Y)x).y = b; // Yak.
    return y;
  }
}

...
var c = new B();
var z = c.createX<Y>(); // Yak. I prefer to not needing to know the type Y
```

I dislike this code, trying to come up with the better way to refactor it. The general idea is quite simple, each class of the hierarchy has factory method to produce an instance of the counterpart class of mirror hierarchy. I get an instance of the root class or derivative class and need to return the instance of counterpart class or its derivative (as root counterpart class). Any ideas or design pattern I can implement instead?

Comment: [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @S.Akbari How do I move the question to codereview?

Comment: Just log in and post your question.

Comment: Tried it, got immediately down-voted for not being the production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have ended up with. All yacks removed. But it is a bit verbose.

```
class X
{
  public string x;
}

class Y : X
{
  public string y;
}

class A
{
  string a;
  protected void setX(X x)
  {
    x.x = a;
  }
  public virtual X createX()
  {
    var x = new X();
    setX(x);
    return x;
  }
}

class B : A
{
  string b;
  protected void setY(Y y)
  {
    base.setX(y);
    y.y = b;
  }
  public override X createX()
  {
    var y = new Y();
    setY(y);
    return y;
  }
}

...
var c = new B();
var z = c.createX();
```

Comment: Nicely done, but remember that doing this you're adding alot of method to your child-class, whether its different to override one. Imagine typing [set..] and your intelliSense pop-up with 42 set-function then you have to select the correct one

Comment: I agree, it is verbose. I just cannot find any better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you want ?

```
class BaseProduct
{
    public string x;
}

class ChildProduct : BaseProduct
{
    public string y;
}

class BaseFactory
{
    string a;
    public virtual BaseProduct buildProduct(BaseProduct product = null)
    {
        if (product == null)
            product = new BaseProduct();

        product.x = a;
        return product;
    }
}

class ChildFactory : BaseFactory
{
    string b;
    public override BaseProduct buildProduct(BaseProduct product = null)
    {
        if (product == null)
            product = new ChildProduct();
        //else if (!(product is ChildProduct))
        //  return null or throw exception

        ((ChildProduct)product).y = b;
        return base.buildProduct(product); //build BaseProduct.x
    }
}

...
var cFactory = new ChildFactory();
var cProduct = c.buildProduct(); //create a ChildProduct with x=a, y=b
```

> buildProduct determine whether it has been requested to create a new
>   product of its own, or some derived-factory requesting it to build its
>   own part only
>
> You should provide some safeguard mechanism of your own, like checking
>   whether the product is a derived class from ChildProduct in
>   ChildFactory.buildProduct. That'll avoid user from passing something like:
>   `childFactory.buildProduct(new BaseProduct()); //yak`

Comment: Well, this takes care of second Yak, though still hate doing the downcast. I come up with different solution to avoid both yaks, though it is slightly verbose.